# Android: IllegalArgumentExcpetion in onItemClickListener

Tags: android, illegalargumentexception

My issue is within my onItemClickListener method. When it gets the line where it assigns 'selectedEmail'. The logcat claims that there is no column named Email so I am not sure where the actual problem is.

Code for ContactsMenu class

```
package com.emailandcontactmanager;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.SimpleCursorAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class ContactsMenu extends Activity {


    ListView listView;
    public static final String fields[] = { DatabaseSetup.colName};
    Cursor cursor;

    public static String name;
    public static String email;
    public static String phone1;
    public static String phone2;
    public static String address;
    public static String notes;


    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.managecontacts);
        listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lstContacts); 
        DatabaseSetup.init(this); 

        Button btnAddItem = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnAddContact);
        btnAddItem.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent addItem = new Intent(v.getContext(), AddContact.class);
            startActivity(addItem);
        }
        });

        listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> listView, View view, 
                int position, long id) {
        // Get the cursor, positioned to the corresponding row in the result set
            //cursor = DatabaseSetup.getContactData();
        Cursor cursor = (Cursor) listView.getItemAtPosition(position);
                //change cursor
                String selectedName = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("Name"));
                String selectedEmail = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("Email"));
                String selectedPhone1 = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("Phone1"));
                String selectedPhone2 = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("Phone2"));
                String selectedAddress = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("Address"));
                String selectedNotes = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("Notes"));

                setName(selectedName);
                setName(selectedEmail);
                setName(selectedPhone1);
                setName(selectedPhone2);
                setName(selectedAddress);
                setName(selectedNotes);


                Intent viewItem = new Intent(view.getContext(), ViewContact.class);
                startActivity(viewItem);

        }
        }); 

    }
        @Override
        protected void onPause() {
            listView.setAdapter(null);
            cursor.close();
            DatabaseSetup.deactivate();
            super.onPause();
        }

        @Override
        protected void onResume() {
            super.onResume();
            DatabaseSetup.init(this);
            //Updated
            cursor = DatabaseSetup.getContactData(); 
            SimpleCursorAdapter adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.row, cursor, fields, new int[] {R.id.item_text});
            listView.setAdapter(adapter); 
        }


        public void setName(String selectedName) {
            name = selectedName;
        }

        public void setEmail(String selectedEmail) {
            email = selectedEmail;
        }

        public void setPhone1(String selectedPhone1) {
            phone1 = selectedPhone1;
        }

        public void setPhone2(String selectedPhone2) {
            phone2 = selectedPhone2;
        }

        public void setAddress(String selectedAddress) {
            address = selectedAddress;
        }

        public void setNotes(String selectedNotes) {
            notes = selectedNotes;
        }


        public static String getName() {
            String itemName = name;
            return itemName;        
        }

        public static String getEmail() {
            String itemEmail = email;
            return itemEmail;       
        }

        public static String getPhone1() {
            String itemPhone1 = phone1;
            return itemPhone1;      
        }

        public static String getPhone2() {
            String itemPhone2 = phone2;
            return itemPhone2;      
        }

        public static String getAddress() {
            String itemAddress = address;
            return itemAddress;     
        }

        public static String getNotes() {
            String itemNotes = notes;
            return itemNotes;       
        }

////////////////MENU////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    DialogInterface.OnClickListener dialogClickListener = new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() { 
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) { 
            switch (which){ 
            case DialogInterface.BUTTON_POSITIVE: 
                finish();
                break; 

            case DialogInterface.BUTTON_NEGATIVE: 
                //Nothing happens on No button click, and the menu closes
                break; 
            } 
        } 
    }; 

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu mainmenu) {
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.mainmenu, mainmenu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        final CharSequence[] items = {"Contacts list", "Add Contact"};

        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.help:     AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
                                builder.setTitle("Select a function to revice information about it.");
                                builder.setItems(items, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int selected) {
                                        switch(selected){
                                        case 0:
                                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                                                    "Allows you to view the selected item and make editations to it or delete it.",
                                                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                            break;
                                        case 1:
                                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                                                    "Allows you to add a new contact by bringing up a screen where the nececary information can be entered.",
                                                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                        }
                                    }
                                });
                                builder.show();
                                break;

                                case R.id.back:     AlertDialog.Builder builderBack = new AlertDialog.Builder(this); 
                                                    builderBack.setMessage("Are you sure?").setPositiveButton("Yes", dialogClickListener) 
                                                    .setNegativeButton("No", dialogClickListener).show(); 
                                break;
        }
        return true;

    }
}
```

Code for DatabaseSetup class

```
    package com.emailandcontactmanager;

import android.content.ContentValues; 
import android.content.Context; 
import android.database.Cursor; 
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase; 
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper; 

/* 
 * usage:  
 * DatabaseSetup.init(egActivityOrContext); 
 * DatabaseSetup.createEntry() or DatabaseSetup.getContactNames() or DatabaseSetup.getDb() 
 * DatabaseSetup.deactivate() then job done 
 */ 

class DatabaseSetup extends SQLiteOpenHelper { 
static DatabaseSetup instance = null; 
static SQLiteDatabase db = null; 

public static void init(Context context) { 
    if (null == instance) { 
        instance = new DatabaseSetup(context); 
        } 
    } 

public static SQLiteDatabase getDb() { 
    if (null == db) { 
        db = instance.getWritableDatabase(); 
        } 
    return db; 
    } 

public static void deactivate() { 
    if (null != db && db.isOpen()) { 
        db.close(); 
        } 
    db = null; 
    instance = null; 
    } 

public static long createEntry(String name, String mail, String phone1, 
        String phone2, String address, String notes) { 
    ContentValues cv = new ContentValues(); 
    cv.put(colName, name); 
    cv.put(colMail, mail); 
    cv.put(colPhone1, phone1); 
    cv.put(colPhone2, phone2); 
    cv.put(colAddress, address); 
    cv.put(colNotes, notes); 
    return getDb().insert(contactsTable, null, cv); 

    } 
/*  Old 
public static Cursor getContactNames() { 
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub 
    String[] columns = new String[] {"_id", colName }; 
    return getDb().query(contactsTable, columns, null, null, null, null, 
            null); 
    } 
*/
public static Cursor getContactData(){
    String[] columns = new String[] {"_id", colName, colMail, colPhone1, colPhone2, colAddress, colNotes }; 
    return getDb().query(contactsTable, columns, null, null, null, null, 
            null); 
    }

DatabaseSetup(Context context) { 
    super(context, dbName, null, dbVersion); 
    } 

@Override 
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) { 
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub 
    db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " + contactsTable 
            + " (_id integer primary key autoincrement, " + colName 
            + " TEXT NOT NULL, " + colMail + " TEXT NOT NULL, " + colPhone1 
            + " TEXT NOT NULL, " + colPhone2 + " TEXT NOT NULL, " 
            + colAddress + " TEXT NOT NULL, " + colNotes 
            + " TEXT NOT NULL)"); 

    db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " + templatesTable 
            + " (_id integer primary key autoincrement, " + colSubject 
            + " TEXT NOT NULL, " + colBody + " TEXT NOT NULL)"); 

    db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " + tagsTable 
            + " (_id integer primary key autoincrement, " + colTagName 
            + " TEXT NOT NULL, " + colContact + " TEXT NOT NULL)"); 

    } 

@Override 
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) { 
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + contactsTable); 
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + templatesTable); 
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + tagsTable); 
    onCreate(db); 
    } 

static final String dbName = "DB"; 
static final int dbVersion = 1; 
static final String contactsTable = "Contacts"; 
static final String colName = "Name"; 
static final String colMail = "Email"; 
static final String colPhone1 = "Phone1"; 
static final String colPhone2 = "Phone2"; 
static final String colAddress = "Address"; 
static final String colNotes = "Notes"; 

static final String templatesTable = "Templates"; 
static final String colSubject = "Subject"; 
static final String colBody = "Body"; 

static final String tagsTable = "Tags"; 
static final String colTagName = "Name"; 
static final String colContact = "Contact"; 

}
```

Code for ViewContact class

```
    package com.emailandcontactmanager;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;

public class ViewContact extends Activity {

    EditText nameField, mailield, phoneField1, phoneField2, addressField, notesField;

    String name, mail, phone1, phone2, address, notes;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.viewcontact);

        nameField = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtName);
        mailield = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtMail);
        phoneField1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtPhone1);
        phoneField2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtPhone2);
        addressField = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtAddress);
        notesField = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtNotes);

        name = ContactsMenu.getName();
        mail = ContactsMenu.getEmail();
        phone1 =ContactsMenu.getPhone1();
        phone2 =ContactsMenu.getPhone2();
        address =ContactsMenu.getAddress();
        notes =ContactsMenu.getNotes();

        nameField.setText(name);
        mailield.setText(mail);
        phoneField1.setText(phone1);
        phoneField2.setText(phone2);
        addressField.setText(address);
        notesField.setText(notes);

        Button btnEditContact = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnEditContact);
        btnEditContact.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            editContact();
        }
        });

        Button btnDeleteContact = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnEditContact);
        btnDeleteContact.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            deleteContact();
        }
        });

        Button btnEditTags = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnEditContact);
        btnEditTags.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent editTags = new Intent(v.getContext(), EditContactTags.class);
            startActivity(editTags);
        }
        });

    }

    public void editContact(){

    }

    public void deleteContact(){

    }

    public void setValues(){

    }

}
```

Logcat output

```
10-16 13:37:12.824: D/gralloc_goldfish(869): Emulator without GPU emulation detected.
10-16 13:37:20.553: D/AndroidRuntime(869): Shutting down VM
10-16 13:37:20.553: W/dalvikvm(869): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x409961f8)
10-16 13:37:20.603: E/AndroidRuntime(869): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
10-16 13:37:20.603: E/AndroidRuntime(869): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.emailandcontactmanager/com.emailandcontactmanager.ViewContact}: java.lang.NullPointerException
10-16 13:37:20.603: E/AndroidRuntime(869):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1879)
10-16 13:37:20.603: E/AndroidRuntime(869):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1980)
10-16 13:37:20.603: E/AndroidRuntime(869):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:122)
10-16 13:37:20.603: E/AndroidRuntime(869):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1146)
10-16 13:37:20.603: E/AndroidRuntime(869):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
10-16 13:37:20.603: E/AndroidRuntime(869):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
10-16 13:37:20.603: E/AndroidRuntime(869):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4340)
10-16 13:37:20.603: E/AndroidRuntime(869):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
10-16 13:37:20.603: E/AndroidRuntime(869):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
10-16 13:37:20.603: E/AndroidRuntime(869):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
10-16 13:37:20.603: E/AndroidRuntime(869):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
10-16 13:37:20.603: E/AndroidRuntime(869):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
10-16 13:37:20.603: E/AndroidRuntime(869): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
10-16 13:37:20.603: E/AndroidRuntime(869):  at android.app.Activity.findViewById(Activity.java:1794)
10-16 13:37:20.603: E/AndroidRuntime(869):  at com.emailandcontactmanager.ViewContact.<init>(ViewContact.java:12)
10-16 13:37:20.603: E/AndroidRuntime(869):  at java.lang.Class.newInstanceImpl(Native Method)
10-16 13:37:20.603: E/AndroidRuntime(869):  at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1319)
10-16 13:37:20.603: E/AndroidRuntime(869):  at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1023)
10-16 13:37:20.603: E/AndroidRuntime(869):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1870)
10-16 13:37:20.603: E/AndroidRuntime(869):  ... 11 more
```

Please tell me if I need to clarify the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cursor contains only _id and colName, (Name). It does not contain Email. You have to add it to the projection in order to be able to retreive it.

You'll also need Phone1, Phone2, Address and Notes.

Comment: Thank you. I am not familliar with SQLite or databases in general, same with android. I am not sure however, where I am supposed to assign this to the cursor. I will update my code to show the changes I made.

Comment: that look ok to me. the important part is that the cursor must contain all the element you will read (it is a select _id, name, whatever from table, so you need to select the columns you need)

Comment: Well Im getting a NullPointerException now, any idea what is causing it?

Comment: yes. you are calling findViewById in the init (which basically is before the constructor), which is much before the onCreate, hence before the setContentView. there is no layout to search your views in.

Comment: What do I need to do? Ive edited my code to show the changes in the ViewContact class, but I am still getting Null Pointers

Comment: My mistake, I had setup the EditTexts as textviews in the xml. Sorry for the misunderstanding, and thank you for the help